# Stopping and Restarting a Stopwatch

Tags: java

This compares the time it takes to find the Square root using Math.sqrt and Newton's Method. I am supposed to add methods to this that allows the client to stop and restart the stop watch, but I'm not sure how to do this. Searching other questions didn't result in much luck, unfortunately. As this is for a class, I don't want the outright answer given to me, but some advice, or a link to a tutorial on how to accomplish my goal would be nice. Thanks for any help.

```
public class Stopwatch 
    {
private final long start;

public Stopwatch()
{ start = System.currentTimeMillis(); }

public double elapsedTime()
{
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    return (now - start) / 1000.0;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int N = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

    double totalMath = 0.0;
    Stopwatch swMath = new Stopwatch();
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        totalMath += Math.sqrt(i);
    double timeMath = swMath.elapsedTime();

    double totalNewton = 0.0;
    Stopwatch swNewton = new Stopwatch();
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        totalNewton += Newton.sqrt(i);
    double timeNewton = swNewton.elapsedTime();

    System.out.println(totalNewton/totalMath);
    System.out.println(timeNewton/timeMath);
}

}
```

Comment: You dont have to create instance of same class you are in, you can call those methods directly like `methodName();` and even if you want to call them then I think one instance is fine.

Answer (score 0):

create another attribute called `timeElapsedUntilLastStop` of type long.

Create a method called stop which does the exact thing as elapsedTime but rather than returning adds to the current value of `timeElapsedUntilLastStop`.

`restart()` method should initialise the start variable which should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

It's great that you are honest about this is for a class and that you don't want the answer given to you. That's a good start for learning :)

Here's how I would approach the task:

First, I'd just define the missing methods. Then, I'd start writing (as inline comments) what the methods should do. What does it mean to reset the stop watch, and what does it mean to stop it? You can draw parallels to a "real life" stopwatch. This should get you started thinking, and once you have defined the rules, it should be possible to translate this into code.

Maybe this is a little more abstract than you expected, but I'm sure you'll get there with the correct attitude, as you seem to have! Good luck!